# The rows of table are back to their places after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, unobtrusive-javascript

I was making a feature with which you can swap the rows in table. It works great, but after refreshing the page, if I swapped some rows, the rows are back to the place, where they have been before swapping. I'd like to know, why is that happening and how to avoid that. This is the code of the feature, if someone needs it:

```
swapRows = function(rowTable) {
    rowTable.find(".glyphicon-sort").click( function() {
        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        row.insertBefore( row.prev() );
    } );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because after refreshing, your page returns to its initial state (from server, or cache), duh.

To retain the state, you have several options: AJAX (so that you don't have your page refreshed), or HTML5 history state manipulation, or local storage etc., all of which are beyond the scope of this question I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm familiar with ajax, can you explain or give an example, how can I save the state?

Comment: I mean, you can use AJAX for requests *from* this page, so that users won't navigate away from it, and cause the page to be refreshed when they go back. It's not that you can use AJAX to *save the state* in this case though.

Comment: @user3130843 I think you should use cookies to persist the state in your particular problem, so when you refresh the page the Web browser will read cookie information of particular rows that were swapped and will swap them accordingly. You can create cookies directly in your javascript, or in the server. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because jQuery is a client side technology and the data is not persisted between requests. When you refresh your page you make new request to the server, which in turn respond with a new page (.html) with a default state. 
In order to save this data between requests you can use cookies.